# Javascript: strip first and last \ from regExp variable

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm cobbling together a script which maps mouse X,Y coordinates to an axis grid. The resulting variable will then be passed to CSS transform property. I'm getting all the numbers I need, but I'm stuck on the last part, which is to remove the \ around the result, which has been converted to a regular expression so as to allow for negative integers.

```
var resultX = RegExp(Math.round(mousePos.x/6.6) -60);
resultX = resultX.replace(/\//g,'');
```

The final stage (stripping the slashes) throws an error no matter how I do it. I've tried encapsulating `.replace` in a function, and using `return`, but I continue to get the same error:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating
>   'resultX.replace(///g,'')')

I'm stuck, and haven't been able to find the solution anywhere. Perhaps the problem is that my variable isn't a true string? Or maybe someone has a suggestion for a better way to allow for negative integers.

JS fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/wAKnY/

Comment: Why are you making a regexp *to pass to a regexp* in the first place?  There's no need for a regex here.  I think your brain is tired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like JayC mentioned in the comments, there doesn't seem to be a reason to convert to a RegExp in the first place, so I would just recommend removing the enclosing `RegExp()`.

However, if you require that for some reason that isn't apparent here, you can then call `toString()` on it to enable the `replace` function to behave correctly:

```
resultX = resultX.toString().replace(/\//g,'');
```

Answer (score 0):

As JayC said, you don't need a regexp in the first place.

```
var resultX = (Math.round(mousePos.x/6.6)-60).toString;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
resultX = resultX.toString().replace(/\//g, '');
resultY = resultY.toString().replace(/\//g, '');
```